# How to sum each 3 rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data similar as i write like this in SQL

```
|   A    |   B    |
Justin       2
Selena       1
Thompson     4
Justin       6
Selena       2
Thompson     4
```

Anyone can help me how to use SUM function but sum each 3 rows or group by column A, that i want have a new data like this

```
|   A    |   B    |   C   |
Justin       2        2
Selena       1        1
Thompson     4        4
Justin       6        8
Selena       2        3
Thompson     4        8
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions . . . but you need a column that specifies the ordering:

```
select t.*,
       sum(b) over (partition by a order by <ordering col>) as c
from t;
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, without a column that specifies the ordering, your results cannot be consistent.  However, if you have no ordering column, you could create one using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(b) over (partition by a order by seqnum) as c
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

The ordering will be non-deterministic so the results could be accumulated in any order -- even on different runs of the query.